# Can't execute hdiutil create from remote machine

Tags: backup, osx-snow-leopard, disk-image

I have an iMac with the HD split into two equal size partitions.  Both partitions are bootable with Snow Leopard.  I then start-up partition 1 with an admin user account.

I want to create a disk image of partition 2 and save the .dmg file on partition 1.  I have to do this remotely from a box running Linux.

The shell command I'm using is

```
ssh <username>@<ipaddress> "echo password | sudo -S hdiutil create -puppetstrings -srcfolder /Volumes/Part2 /Users/Shared/image.dmg"
```

When I run the command from the remote shell it consistently dies around 98%, but when I run the hdiutil from / of partition 1 on the box hosting partition 2, everything works as expected.

I've been able to run other hdiutil commands from the remote shell.  I'm only having a problem with the create verb.

I don't believe it's a network issue because it always dies in the same place.  I'm puzzled why the same command would behave differently when executed from a remote shell.

Comment: Now I just had it die on the local box.  I'm now thinking it has something to do with the puppetstrings option or the path provided before the image name.  When I successfully ran the command I didn't have puppetstrings or a path.  I suspect puppetstrings because the numbers are off.  The command dies with the console showing 78.651413 four times before going to -1.000000.  Plus 78% isn't an accurate reflection of the new image file size compared to the expected image file size.

Comment: There is something strange with puppetstrings.  Normally I would kill the script when I see the console display percent: -1.000000 because the man doc says that is an error code.  This time I was doing a different task and didn't kill the script and when I came back I saw the image had been successfully created.  So I was getting thrown off by the feedback from puppetstrings because when I don't have that feedback I just wait for the shell to come back without killing the script.  Anyone else use the puppetstrings option with the create verb?

Comment: As per [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html), a value of `-1` means it's performing an operation *"that will take an indeterminate amount of time to complete"*. Sounds about right, as I remember seeing the indeterminate progress bar indicator when I started a similar action from Disk Utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Beck for pointing out my error.  I don't know how I misread that in my reading of the man doc.